# Solo mining on OS X with Diablo Miner

Tags: mac, solo-mining, diablominer

I want to test Solo mining on OS X with Diablo Miner, so I pass options:

```
./DiabloMiner-OSX.sh -u my_user -p my_pass -r 8332
```

and I get:

```
[5/1/13 11:01:37 PM] Started                                         
[5/1/13 11:01:37 PM] Connecting to: http://localhost:8332/                           
[5/1/13 11:01:37 PM] Using Apple OpenCL 1.1 (Aug 10 2012 19:59:48)                       
[5/1/13 11:01:38 PM] Added GeForce 9600M GT (#1) (4 CU, local work size of 512)              
[5/1/13 11:01:38 PM] ERROR: Cannot connect to localhost: Connection refused                  
[5/1/13 11:01:38 PM] Added GeForce 9400M (#2) (2 CU, local work size of 512)                 
[5/1/13 11:01:38 PM] ERROR: Cannot connect to localhost: Connection refused                  
[5/1/13 11:01:38 PM] ERROR: Cannot connect to localhost: Connection refused                  
[5/1/13 11:01:39 PM] ERROR: Cannot connect to localhost: Connection refused
```

What could be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure That you have, in your `bitcoin.conf` file located in `~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin` at least the following:

```
server=1
rpcuser=<username>
rpcpassword=<your_password>
```

Restart Bitcoin client, enjoy Bitcoin solo mining. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you must have a locally-running instance of Bitcoin-Qt or `bitcoind` running with its JSON-RPC interface active.

Comment: I compiled bitcoind, but did not find info about how to activate that interface

Comment: See [Running](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-osx.md#running) in the OSX build instructions.